# RJ45 locking clip breaks when I crimp, how do I crimp without breaking?

Tags: ethernet

I purchased a crimping tool from Ace Hardware, and every time I crimp with it, it presses down on the locking tab so that when I pull the plug out of the crimping tool it doesn't work as a lock anymore.

How do I do this without breaking that piece?  If I press down too lightly the pins don't go in, if I press down hard I break the clip.

Attached is a picture of the clip so you know exactly what I'm talking about.

[image: rj45 lock clip]

Answer (score 1):

Could try putting it next to the heater so that it is less brittle when it goes into the criming tool? Else put something between on top to reduce the pressure (though this is possibly an oxymoron as it may actually increase the pressure required to crimp it properly)?